# Spring Import Can't See Resources

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, spring

I'm using Spring to handle my dependency injection and I am currently writing a jar that makes use of a homegrown `logging-1.0.jar` that I also made some time ago. I am writing this inside Eclipse, which may be important.

That `logging-1.0.jar` has a critical config file in it called `logging-base.xml` where all sorts of environmental properties get set so that my logger works correctly.

My new jar is compiling/building in Ant fine, but at runtime is throwing an exception stating:

```
Exception in thread "main"     
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: 
Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location 
[classpath:logging-base.xml] Offending resource: class path resource
[spring/client-config.xml]; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException:
Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema
namespace [http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring]

Offending resource: class path resource [logging-base.xml]
```

So it seems that Spring cannot find my `logging-base.xml` file as its not "in the classpath". In my project I have a `lib/` directory where all of my dependent jars are stored. When I copy a new jar into this directory, I just right-click it and go **Build Path >> Add to Build Path** and Eclipse makes a reference of that jar available to the runtime.

Of all the jars under my `lib/` directory, **logger-1.0.jar** has a distinct icon next to its name in the package explorer. Its icon has a little tiny question-mark ("?") in it.

So I'm *guessing* that, somehow, my logging jar isn't configured correctly, and as a result, isn't adding its `logging-base.xml` file to the classpath. As such, at runtime, Spring can't find it.

But that's where my knowledge of Eclipse and Spring grinds to a halt.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you using camel-spring jars as part of your deployment?

Comment: Nope - never thought that would even be an issue. What should I try? I have camel-core, -jms, -spring, -spring-ws in my repository.

Comment: The issue on hand is It looks like you have this name space http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring in your client-config.xml, Spring usually has name space handlers defined for them, they are in file called spring.handlers and are included in the jars in this case (camel-spring-X.jar). For this specific deployment are you using camel?

Comment: Thanks Prasanna! If you change your comment to an answer I'll check it for you - that's exactly what it was!

Comment: I am glad the issue is resolved, I replied it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue might be with spring handlers, You might have defined this name space http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring in your client-config.xml, Spring usually has name space handlers defined for every name space that is defined in the application context. These handlers are defined in a file called spring.handlers and are included in the respective jars in this case (camel-spring-X.jar).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add `xerces.jar` and  in `jre6\lib\ext` directory, Just try this out.. coz it helped me solve this problem !

Comment: Rakesh - I appreciate your suggestion, but can you elaborate as to why this would work?!?! It seems like a strange "hack"! before I got this error I was receiving SAXExceptions because some of the XML itself was invalid, so I know its validating/parsing the schemas the right way. Explicitly adding Xerces to the JVM's private library just feels...hacky. (But thank you for taking the time to make the suggestion!)

Comment: @Mara, the xerces library is used to parse the xml stuffs in your web application. Well i didn't try to dig much deeper into this.. you can find more info [here](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/)